# When Joining multiple views together I get duplicate records and I can't see a way out of it

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-view

I have a log table that logs the assignment of Service Managers, Resource Managers, and, Employees to "Slots" within a department. I know the slot logic is convoluted but it was a specific request for it to function this way.

Since I have multiple ID's (ResourceManagerID, EmployeeID, and, ServiceManagerID) all foreign keyed to EmployeeID in this log table I have to create multiple views and then Join them together in order to get the data in the correct format. I have done this already one of the views called "VMasterData" and I based this one on that one but I don't seem to be getting the same functionality for it.

Below is the Slot table:

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].Slots(
    SlotID                          INTEGER         IDENTITY        NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY(SlotID)
);
GO
```

Below it the Table structure for the Log table:

```
GO
     CREATE TABLE [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].DepartmentSlotsLog(
    DepartmentID                    INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    SlotID                          INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID                      INTEGER                             NULL,
    ResourceManagerID               INTEGER                             NULL,
    ServiceManagerID                INTEGER                             NULL,
    LogDate                         DATETIME                        NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentID, SlotID, LogDate)
);
GO
```

Below is the Department Table

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].Departments(
    DepartmentID                    INTEGER         IDENTITY        NOT NULL,
    DepartmentName                  VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    AllocatedSlots                  INTEGER                         NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentID)
);
GO
```

Below is the Employee Table.

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].Employees(
    EmployeeID                      INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    FirstName                       VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    MiddleName                      VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    LastName                        VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    EmployeeType                    INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    EmployeeStatus                  INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    EmployeeLevel                   INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    EmployeeRole                    INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    Proactive                       BIT                             NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID)
);
GO
```

Below is the Employee Slots Log Data:

```
CREATE VIEW VEmployeeSlotsLogData

AS
SELECT 
    D.DepartmentID                          AS DepartmentID,
    DSL.SlotID                              AS SlotID,
    D.DepartmentName                        AS DepartmentName,
    DSL.ResourceManagerID                   AS ResourceManagerID,
    DSL.ServiceManagerID                        AS ServiceManagerID,
    E.EmployeeID                            AS EmployeeID,
    E.LastName + ', ' + E.FirstName         AS EmployeeFullName,
    E.EmployeeRole                          AS EmployeeRole,
    E.EmployeeLevel                         AS EmployeeRoleLevel


FROM

    Departments         AS  D
        JOIN DepartmentSlotsLog     AS  DSL
            ON D.DepartmentID = DSL.DepartmentID

        LEFT JOIN Employees         AS  E
            ON DSL.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
```

Below is the Resource Manager View:

```
CREATE VIEW VResourceManagerLogData

AS
SELECT 
    D.DepartmentID                          AS DepartmentID,
    DSL.SlotID                              AS SlotID,
    D.DepartmentName                        AS DepartmentName,
    DSL.ResourceManagerID                   AS ResourceManagerID,
    E.LastName + ', ' + E.FirstName         AS EmployeeFullName,
    E.EmployeeRole                          AS EmployeeRole,
    E.EmployeeLevel                         AS EmployeeRoleLevel,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DSL.LogDate, 107)  AS RecordDate

FROM

    Departments         AS  D
        LEFT JOIN DepartmentSlotsLog        AS  DSL
            ON D.DepartmentID = DSL.DepartmentID

        LEFT JOIN Employees         AS  E
            ON DSL.ResourceManagerID = E.EmployeeID
```

Below is the Service Manager View

```
CREATE VIEW VServiceManagerLogData

AS
SELECT 
    D.DepartmentID                          AS DepartmentID,
    DSL.SlotID                              AS SlotID,
    D.DepartmentName                        AS DepartmentName,
    DSL.ServiceManagerID                    AS ServiceManagerID,
    E.LastName + ', ' + E.FirstName         AS EmployeeFullName,
    E.EmployeeRole                          AS EmployeeRole,
    E.EmployeeLevel                         AS EmployeeRoleLevel,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DSL.LogDate, 107)  AS RecordDate


FROM

    Departments         AS  D
        LEFT JOIN DepartmentSlotsLog        AS  DSL
            ON D.DepartmentID = DSL.DepartmentID

        LEFT JOIN Employees         AS  E
            ON DSL.ServiceManagerID = E.EmployeeID
```

Below is the MastLogView I am Attempting to create:

```
CREATE VIEW VMasterLogData

AS
SELECT 
    VESLD.DepartmentID                  AS DepartmentID,
    VESLD.DepartmentName                AS DepartmentName,
    VESLD.SlotID                        AS SlotID,
    VESLD.EmployeeID                    AS EmployeeID,
    VESLD.EmployeeFullName              AS EmployeeFullName,
    VESLD.EmployeeRole                  AS EmployeeRole,
    VESLD.EmployeeRoleLevel             AS EmployeeRoleLevel,
    VESLD.ResourceManagerID             AS RMID,
    VRMLD.EmployeeFullName              AS RMFullName,
    VESLD.ServiceManagerID              AS SMID,
    VSMLD.EmployeeFullName              AS SMFullName,
    VSMLD.RecordDate                    AS RecordDate

FROM

    VEmployeeSlotsLogData  AS VESLD
        LEFT JOIN VResourceManagerLogData   AS VRMLD
        ON VESLD.ResourceManagerID = VRMLD.ResourceManagerID
       AND VESLD.SlotID            = VRMLD.SlotID

        LEFT JOIN VServiceManagerLogData    AS VSMLD
        ON VESLD.ServiceManagerID = VSMLD.ServiceManagerID
       AND VESLD.SlotID           = VSMLD.SlotID
```

Below The second screen shot is of the records in their unjoined format. I get 3360 Records which is correct.

The first Screen shot is of the master log after I run it, Notice once a resource manager is added or a service manager is added, it doubles up on the entries, I kind of understand why this would happen, but I can't figure out how to stop it. I got it to work on a different log table with this same approach, but no dice this time. I receive 4000+ records and that just a little too many.

*** EDIT REMOVED SCREENSHOTS ***

any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include the SQL for VEmployeeSlotsLogData

Comment: You might try adding a where clause in your MasterLogView with: `WHERE VRMLD.ResourceManagerID IS NOT NULL AND VSMLD.ServiceManagerID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Comment: This seems likely to be a common error where people want the join on a shared key of some aggregations (each possibly involving joining) but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. (If you don't want a binary join to duplicate input rows as output subrows then you must join on a PK/UNIQUE of at least one table.) PS Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Less data please.

Comment: Philipxy, that is confusing you simultaneously asked me for more data then told me I gave too much. Which is it?

Comment: The second screenshot is the data I wish to make more readable by way of a join, the first screen shot has all the data in the format I want just doubles up some records. Short of dropping the entire schema and all the bulk inserts to recreate all this data I don't know how to give you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after mentally stressing my brain, I remembered about sub-queries. Here is my simple and surprisingly fast solution.

```
CREATE VIEW VMasterLogData

AS

SELECT
   DSL.DepartmentID,
   DSL.EmployeeID,
   (SELECT E.LastName + ', ' + E.FirstName AS FullName FROM Employees AS E WHERE E.EmployeeID = DSL.EmployeeID) AS EmployeeName,
   DSL.ResourceManagerID,
   (SELECT E.LastName + ', ' + E.FirstName AS FullName FROM Employees AS E WHERE E.EmployeeID = DSL.ResourceManagerID) AS RMName,
   DSL.ServiceManagerID,
   (SELECT E.LastName + ', ' + E.FirstName AS FullName FROM Employees AS E WHERE E.EmployeeID = DSL.ServiceManagerID) AS SMName,
   DSL.LogDate

FROM 
   DepartmentSlotsLog  AS DSL
```